# Webpack failing to compile till electron is closed

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron

https://github.com/StephenGrider/UpStarMusic/

I cloned the above git repository and was trying to run it after installing dependcies using `npm run start`

.There is only connection refused error in electron console and the webpack never compiles until the window is closed and once its closed the webpack compiles successfully.

I don't know react was following a tutorial and this was related to MongoDb and for that the tutor was using a react node template to display the data

but am stuck as I cannot move and tried contacting the tutor but he is not responding and after checking git many had this issue .

Comment: try running the start script in two different terminal, i.e: one: electron ., second terminal: webpack-dev-server.

Comment: @PlayMa256 it worked can you tell me why it was happening ??

Comment: those two commands are blockers, and one & was missing in the command. Better to have those two running separatly.